# Ruby on rails: filtering search box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, dictionary

I am creating a rails application that replicates an online dictionary. I have already implemented the alphabetical_paginate gem but I want to add a search bar that can filter through the words as you type for the word you're looking for. Is there a gem that could do this or is there a straight forward way of filtering with a search bar?

My controller looks like this:

```
def index
  @words, @alphaParams = Word.all.alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:default_field => "all"}){|word| word.word}
end
```

View:

```
<%= alphabetical_paginate @alphaParams %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Word</th>
      <th>Wordtype</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

<div id="pagination_table">
  <tbody>
    <% @words.each do |word| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= word.word %></td>
        <td><%= word.wordtype %></td>
        <td><%= word.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', word %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Datatables is what you are looking for.

Here are the links to get started:

1. http://datatables.net/
2. https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails